# Send ajax request on click event in backbone js

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-model

Here's the code

This is **model**

```
 var TodoItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
     url: 'list.php',
     DeleteTabItem: function (child, parent) {
         jQuery.ajax({
             url: 'delete.php',
         });
     }
 });
```

This is **view**

```
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.entry-title',
    template: _.template(''),
    KeyPressEvent: function () {
        this.model.DeleteTabItem();
    }
});
```

Is this correct way of sending **ajax** request.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In backbone model, instead of url,

use : `urlRoot`: "yoururl",

```
Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'list.php' 
});
```

`url` would be used in `collections`

For sending data through view :

```
this.model.save(sendData, { success, error });
```

where **sendData = { data preferably in json }**

You will have to bind the model with your view like :

```
var todoView = var TodoView(model:TodoItem);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Roy. How to send values through GET or POST    Sorry i dont have enough reputation to upvote your answer

Comment: Thanks Roy it helped me out to get the solution

Comment: Is it possible to use anothe urlRoot within the same model?

Comment: No.. But why is that? if you need to have multiple ajax requests sent, you should take a look at how collections(more than 1 models) work.. Or you write another model and instead of this.model.save(), use newmodelname.save(). Declare the new model jsut before this call.. :)..

Comment: Thanks Roy I didn't read about collections so i was doing like that.Now i will learn collection

Answer (score 1):

In Backbone world, we usually use multiple models and collection instead of handle data directly via JQuery AJAX function.

So you just need to persist your values into model or collections, and execute correspond actions, like fetch(), save(), destroy()...They have default request type.

As for your code, you still can use new function "DeleteTabItem", but inside, the better way is call some model or collection's **destroy** action.